# How is it possible for the repository parameter to be null?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, controller, repository, symfony-3.2

I'm trying to enhance an old project built with symfony 3.2 but i'm facing a weird issue.
I'm just trying to get some data in my controller to send it to the view. But, for some reason i can't reach the repository function i made from my controller.
Here is the code:

The Repository

```
class CommandeRepository extends EntityRepository
{
   ...

   public function getSPSExpe()
   {
     $dql = 'SELECT .....(not showing it for security reason)';

     $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('default');
     $query = $em->createQuery($dql);
     $query->setParameters(array(
        'idSite' => 201,
        'idEtat' => 9
     ));
     $results = $query->getResult();
     return $results;
   }
}
```

The Controller

```
class ExpeditionController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function expeditionSPS(CommandeRepository $repo)
    {
       $results = $repo->getSPSExpe();

       return $this->render('WorkflowFrontOfficeBundle:Expedition:expeditionSPS.html.twig', 
       ['results' => $results]);
    }
```

}

It seems fine right??!   but i get this error :
Controller ... requires that you provide a value for the "$repo" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one

And when i set CommandeRepository $repo = null as a parameter i get:
calling getSPSExpe() on null ....

Do you have any idea about what should be done here?
Thanks a lot for your time.

Thanks to Delboy i looked a bit in service container of older symfony versions. I executed "php bin/console debug:container repository 
and got:

```
    Information for Service "doctrine.orm.container_repository_factory"
===================================================================

 ------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Option             Value                                                                 
 ------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Service ID         doctrine.orm.container_repository_factory                             
  Class              Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ContainerRepositoryFactory  
  Tags               -                                                                     
  Public             no                                                                    
  Synthetic          no                                                                    
  Lazy               no                                                                    
  Shared             yes                                                                   
  Abstract           no                                                                    
  Autowired          no                                                                    
  Autowiring Types   -                                                                     
 ------------------ ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Couldn't find yet how to set autowired to yes for this class.

Comment: Where do you call `$whatever->expeditionSPS($repo)`?

Comment: in fact i think your autowiring isn't set up correctly, since that's a controller class

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, it might be a lead. i don"t know much about old symfony versions of services.yml but i'm gonna search a bit about that.

Comment: is this an old symfony? autowiring didnt exist, you'll have to pass in your repo to your method or via controller constructor or a setter method

Comment: Yes it is version 3.2.4